# Is there a measurement standard e.g. for coast lines?

Tags: distance, measurements, precision

When watching discovery & documentary shows, coastlines are apparently defined to be just long enough to fit some explanation or a discussed topic.

The [coastline paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) is a well-established fact describing how the measurement is defined by the precision of measurement.

By specifying some sensible alignment, precision and assumptions for e.g. tides, one could imagine a well-defined algorithm for proper & comparable measurement (e.g. by rasterization).

So is there any established standard for measuring coast lines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, GIS SE is not a discussion site. We use a "Focused question / Best answer" model which is not compatible with a "Why can't folks agree on a standard?" question. We do have a chat room feature, but it is underutilized.